# How to compile Unreal 5 project in VS Code without launching the game?

Tags: visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

How to compile Unreal 5 project in VS Code without launching the game or the editor ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top menu, Terminal->Run Build Task

Usually you use the 'Editor' suffix 'Development' config. The 'Editor' suffix config would be for this project 'project1Editor (platform) Development Build'.

You can also try Rebuild if the Build has any trouble.